# Calculating the exact value of this infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

I am having trouble finding a way to calculate the exact value of this infinite series, all i know is that each term gets closer and closer to zero.

Here's the question:

Calculate the exact value of,

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty$ $\frac{3^n + 1}{4^n}$

I started to write out the terms but i don't see a pattern.

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty$ $\frac{3^n + 1}{4^n}$ = 2 + 1 + $\frac{5}{8}$+ $\frac{7}{16}$+$\frac{41}{128}$+$\frac{61}{256}$+$\frac{365}{2048}$+...

If anyone can help that would be great!

Comment: it can be broken down into two geometric series summing (1/4)^n and (3/4)^n.

Comment: I am currently working on finding the limit of the partial sums of them two :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the sum $\sum(\frac34)^n+\sum(\frac14)^n$.

Each of those are geometric series.  So it equals

$\frac1{1-3/4} + \frac1{1-1/4} = 4 + 4/3 = 16/3$

Comment: thanks, i just got the same answer as you there, i had a "blank memory" moment and just thought this was more difficult than it was, thank for your answer aswell.

Comment: @ConnorGaughan No problem

Answer (score 4):

Well this can be split into two terms:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\;{\frac{3^n}{4^n} } + {\frac{1}{4^n}}$$
$$ \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\;{{\bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)}^n}+\;{{\bigg(\frac{1}{4}\bigg)}^n }$$
$$ \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\;{{\bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)}^n}\;\;+\;\;\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\;{{\bigg(\frac{1}{4}\bigg)}^n }$$

Now these are two simple geometric progressions.
Using formula: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\;r^n\;=\;\; \frac{1}{1-r} \;\; for\;\;r<0 $$
We'll get $$\frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{4}}\;+\;\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}$$
$$=4+\frac{4}{3}$$
$$=\frac{16}{3}$$

 
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A more general way to solve problems like this is to use recursion to represent infinite patterns in a finite way. This recursion should be broken up into a sum of two recursions. Once it is turned into recursion, you are not dealing with infinity at all. $S_1$ and $S_2$ also solve individually for finite sum of $n$ terms as well. The really critical thing is that $S_1$ isn't the sum. $S_1 - Tail[S_1,n]$ is the sum; because $X = Sum[X,n] + Tail[X,n]$, for some infinite sum $X$. It is important to explicitly include $n$ as a largest actual number you considered, and the $Tail[S_1,n]$ represents what comes after it, so that $S_1$ has the same value, no matter how large $n$ gets:

$
\begin{align}
 S &= \sum_n^{0 \dots \infty}\big(\frac{3}{4}\big)^n + 
      \sum_n^{0 \dots \infty}\big(\frac{1}{4}\big)^n \\
   &= S_1 + S_2 \\
 S_1 &= 1 + \frac{3}{4}\ S_1 \\
     &= 4 \\
     &= \big(\frac{3}{4}\big)^0 + \big(\frac{3}{4}\big)^1 + \big(\frac{3}{4}\big)^2+\cdots+\big(\frac{3}{4}\big)^n+\big(\frac{3}{4}\big)^{n+1}\ S_1 \\
 4(1 - \big(\frac{3}{4}\big)^{n+1}) &= Sum[S_1,n] \\
 S_1\ \frac{1}{4} &= 1 \\
 S_1 &= 4 \\
 S_2 &= 1 + \frac{1}{4}\ S_2 \\
 S_2\ \frac{3}{4} &= 1 \\
 S_2 &= \frac{4}{3} \\
 \frac{4}{3}(1 - \big(\frac{1}{4}\big)^{n+1}) &= Sum[S_2,n] \\
   S &= 4 + \frac{4}{3} = \frac{16}{3} \\
   Sum[S,n] &= 4(1 - \big(\frac{3}{4}\big)^{n+1}) + \frac{4}{3}(1 - \big(\frac{1}{4}\big)^{n+1})
\end{align}
$